migration in inital setup in adonis.js project
I ran the command node ace migration:run in an adonis.js application, to create the initial database schema, and I am getting the error:
internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
   Error: Failed to load native binding
    at Object.<anonymous> \node_modules\@swc\core\binding.js:333:11)   
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)

what do I need to do to fix this error?
I am new to adonis.js. I am expecting to understand what caused the error and the fix to the error.
